# Codeigniter 4 - как отобразить 404?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Начал разбираться с новой версией фреймворка. Вроде все неплохо, но возник очень глупый вопрос, на который офф.мануал не дал ответа: какой метод отвечает за отображение 404 страницы? В Codeigniter 3 все было просто - в нужном месте контроллера вызывали функцию show_404(). А как это сделать теперь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение нашлось здесь: [CodeIgniter 4 User Guide - Error Handling](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/errors.html?#pagenotfoundexception)

В нужном месте контроллера выбрасываем исключение:

```
throw \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException::forPageNotFound();
```